# How to remove (not verified) status in anonymous comments?

Tags: 8, theming, users, comments

If I allow users to comment while they are not logged in (anonymous authors), they will have a 'not verified' tag next to their name in the comments of my site. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `hook_preprocess_username` and remove the `extra` variable:

```
function THEME_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  $variables['extra'] = '';
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but, I wondering if this will apply for all place in my site or only in comments?

Comment: It will apply anywhere that uses the `username` theme to render that info @Carlos. Can’t really be more specific than that I’m afraid

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible to change that in the backend.

`Appearance` » `Settings` » *uncheck* `User verification status in comments` in the `Page Element Display` section